# Highlight Bound Control on Validation Failure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, .net-4.5

How can I highlight (ie: `BackColor`) a bound `TextBox` upon failed validation?

In other words, I want something like:

```
private void myTextBox_AfterCheckingValidation( object sender, EventArgs e )
{ // Which event would this be?
    if ( theValidationFailed ) // <-- how do i get this?
        myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else
        myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

... or something like

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool vStatus = myTextBox.Validate(); // <-- How could I acheive this?

    if (vStatus)
        myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else
        myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

Notes:

- Since the `TextBox` is bound, the `DataSet` implements the validation check.
- The form `AutoValidate` property is `EnableAllowFocusChange` to allow the user to continue filling out the form.
- The `TextBox.Validating` event occurs before the `DataSet` performs the data validation, so I can't check it here.
- The `TextBox.Validated` event does not occur for a failed validation, so I can't highlight the control from here.
- There doesn't seem to be a `ValidationFailed` event.

Possible (probably bad) approaches:

1. On `TextBox.TextChanged`, call `this.Validate()` for the form.  However, this checks all controls, not just this specific one.
2. Disable `CausesValidation` for all controls.  Check the validation of a specific control, by enabling its `CausesValidation` and calling the form `this.Validate()` method.  This seems way too complex to be an appropriate solution.
3. Write my own validation check.  This seems redundant and unnecessary as it probably wouldn't match the `DataSet` data validation exactly.
4. On `TextBox.Validating` set a short background timer. On `TextBox.Validated` cancel the timer.  On `Timer.Expired`, set the background color.  This approach is definitely a hack, but might get the job done.
5. Use some method of the typed `DataSet`, `DataTable`, `DataRow`, or `DataColumn` to check the validation explicitly?  (... haven't found anything relevant yet).

I've searched online.  I've dug through the methods, properties, and events for the `TextBox`, `DataSet`, `BindingSource`, and other relevant options.  I am completely at a loss for how to implement what seems to be such a simple task.

Comment: We can't write your program for you. You need to do some research, write some code, and when you have a more specific problem, then come back and post something.

Comment: Without getting specific with WinForms, the way I would do it is create an interface for the validator, have a field for it in your Form, call the validation method at every input (using events) and change background color based on the returned value.

Comment: You state that the dataset handles the validation. What kind of validation are you doing in your dataset and did you consider using a business layer?

Comment: The `DataSet` must perform some type of implicit validation to know if the `TextBox.Text` is a valid numeric value to store in the database column.  The validation check itself is performed in the background somewhere (with code generated by the DataSet designer I assume).

Comment: 3 & 4 seem ok.
3 -> you need to write your own, As it needs to update the coloring (The the default one, and wrap it?).
4 -> Why use a timer. Just assume failure, on Validating set to red. On Validated set to clear.

Comment: @Steven: Done, plus affiliated information, Suggest you add comment with the option you chose.

Comment: Please explain any close/down votes for my question, so I can write better questions down the road.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx and override the Validating event for the control. You write the validation logic and when it the condition is not met, set the cancel property of the CancelEventArgs object to true. This will suppress all events thereafter and subsequently prevent form submission. In the same location, you can add any UI behaviors you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JDennis I want to handle the result of the provided data source validation logic, not override the logic with my own.

Comment: @Steven It is common to have validation in the data layer, business layer and UI layer. The easiest way to implement UI behaviors based upon validation, is to implement validation checking on the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no direct location to update the `TextBox`'s color.

The actual validation is done by some auto-generated code, and thus is mostly inaccessible.
There is a pre-validation event & a validation successful event. (`Validating` & `Validated`). But not a "*Failed Validation*" Event.

Of your proposed solutions **3 & 4** seem best.

For **3**, you can create your own validator and have it reuse the `DataSet`'s validation logic. This can be messy as the logic is hard to find, and you are merging the validation, with the presentation code.

For **4**, You can use the `Validating` event to set the *color* to **red**. (Assume Failure). Then on the `Validated` event, set *color* to **clear**. This solves the main problem, that there is no clear "*Failed Validation*" Event. (Possible downside, if you need to perform a "heavy" task. Here, it is only a property change, this should not cause a redraw until after the validation finishes.

**EDIT: Final Code** (by Steven)

```
private void myTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void weightTextBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.BackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Option 4: Simple, straightforward.  Edited answer to include my code.